# Active Directory - Copy OrganizationalUnit name to user Location attribute

Tags: active-directory, ldap, location, organizational-unit

Is there a way to programmatically copy the OrganizationalUnit name of an AD user to it's location attribute?

I have several OUs on my AD tree where each of them is related to a physical department of my company. Users were created only with the name attribute to speed up things, but now I need to fulfil their information, and I'm thinking a way of scripting this.

I've tried to get all users properties from `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *`, but the OU only shows up under DistinguishedName, and I have no idea how to copy this property to the user location attribute, filtering out only the OU name (and, if I have sub OUs, group them as OU\subOU).

Answer (score 1):

```
$USERS = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName
foreach($user in $USERS)
{
$copy = (Split-Path $user.CanonicalName -Parent) -replace 'domain.name\\' 
Set-ADUser $user -Replace @{Department=$copy}
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.